# Cause for "XABBA7009: System.InvalidOperationException: PE image does not have metadata." for MAUI Android release image using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, maui

I am able to successfully build a debug image for my mobile app for an Android emulator. When I try to build a Release image, I get the error below. I've tried to clean my build, update all workloads, libraries, software, etc. I'm using Visual Studio version 17.5.3.

I tried to clear my Nuget cache and restored all packages from scratch.

Any leads would be GREATLY appreciated! It appears to me that one of the provided libraries (PE images) may not have been packaged properly. This is a rough guess but I don't know how to narrow down the issue any further.

```
Error       XABBA7009: System.InvalidOperationException: PE image does not have metadata.
   at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader.GetMetadataBlock()
   at System.Reflection.Metadata.PEReaderExtensions.GetMetadataReader(PEReader peReader, MetadataReaderOptions options, MetadataStringDecoder utf8Decoder)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.IsReferenceAssembly(String assembly)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.<AddAssemblies>g__AddAssembliesFromCollection|152_0(ITaskItem[] assemblies, <>c__DisplayClass152_0& )
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.AddAssemblies(ZipArchiveEx apk, Boolean debug, Boolean compress, IDictionary`2 compressedAssembliesInfo, String assemblyStoreApkName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.ExecuteWithAbi(String[] supportedAbis, String apkInputPath, String apkOutputPath, Boolean debug, Boolean compress, IDictionary`2 compressedAssembliesInfo, String assemblyStoreApkName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.BuildApk.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of frustration, I decided to create a new directory, pull all code from my last git push and build from "scratch". That resolved the problem. I'm not sure why a Clean of my solution didn't work. Nonetheless, this more drastic cleaning did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I was going nuts on this..  It's another one of those error messages that refers to something which is not the problem.

For me I had System.Data.SQLite and sqlite-net-pcl installed which appeared to be colliding with each other.

I removed the System.Data.SQLite, cleaned the project (twice due to an error when I attempted to clean the first time) and did a build.  This issue was not present after this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i took the clue from this post.

1. I created a new project
2. added every nuget package my application needed one by one and compiled everytime
3. Found the culprit, it is the serilog.sink.sqlite, so now I use File sink